# Is WiFi safe for humans?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life, radiation, biophysics

I have WiFi on at my home almost all the time. I learned that the frequency of visible light is around several hundreds of THz, while the frequency of wifi is only several GHz, which is only 1:100,000. But I'm not sure how the amplitude of WiFi wave compares to the amplitude of the visible light? Are the frequency and the amplitude the only concerns when we talk about the radiation? Can someone educate me to quantify the effect WiFi radiation could have in our life?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about biology and not physics.

Comment: Meta thread: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5883/